# Is it a good practice to allow field access outside of class or field should always be allowed to access outside through property only?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand proper usage of Field and whether field should be allowed to access by other class or it should be always be through property?

Consider i have a code like below :

```
internal class MyCalculator : IDisposable
    {
        public Type1 type1;
        public MyCalculator(Type1 type1)
        {
           this.type = type1;
        }
    }

internal class Accessor
{
   public void Foo()
   {
     MyCalculator obj = new MyCalculator();
     obj.type1.Id = 10;
   }
}
```

Is this a good practice of allowing access of public fields outside of another class or it should always be through property only?

While I was checking source code of List i saw this :

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
    {
        private const int _defaultCapacity = 4;

        private T[] _items;
        [ContractPublicPropertyName("Count")]
        private int _size;
        private int _version;
    }
```

**private properties** are marked with **underscore** while same **Dictionary private members** were **not marked with Underscore** as shown below :

```
public class Dictionary<TKey,TValue>: IDictionary<TKey,TValue>, IDictionary, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback  {

        private struct Entry {
            public int hashCode;    // Lower 31 bits of hash code, -1 if unused
            public int next;        // Index of next entry, -1 if last
            public TKey key;           // Key of entry
            public TValue value;         // Value of entry
        }

        private int[] buckets;
        private Entry[] entries;
        private int count;
        private int version;
        private int freeList;
        private int freeCount;
}
```

So i am bit confused is there any difference between above 2 i.e List and Dictionary private members or may be i am missing something?

This is not duplicate exactly because I have asked too things and ofcourse i could have mention that in the question but since i did not wanted question of my title to be too big.

Also I am asking this in context of what I have shown in my code(Field and Property code snippet) and whether its a good practice or not in my specific scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**According to [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/PropertiesMatter):**

> There are times when you could use non-private fields, because for whatever reason you don't care about the compatibility reasons above. However, there are still benefits to using properties even for trivial situations:
>
> -There's more fine-grained access control with properties. Need it to be publicly gettable but really only want it set with protected access? No problem (from C# 2 onwards, at least).
>
> -Want to break into the debugger whenever the value changes? Just add a breakpoint in the setter.
>
> -Want to log all access? Just add logging to the getter.
>   Properties are used for data binding; fields aren't.
>
> > In almost all cases, fields should be private. Not just non-public, but private. With automatic properties in C# 3, there's basically no cost in readability or the amount of code involved to use a property instead of a field. Very occasionally you might find a genuinely good reason, but think long and hard about it before committing to that choice, particularly if you'll be exposing it beyond internal access.

**and for the underscore:**

There's no language-defined meaning - it's just a convention some people use to distinguish instance variables from local variables. Other variations include m_foo (and s_foo or g_foo or static variables) or mFoo; alternatively some people like to prefix the local variables (and parameters) instead of the instance variables.

just when ever you want to create a variable inside class put a simple {set;get;} in front of it. no harm done.

```
public int a {set; get;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time and for your kind efforts towards helping me.Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use properties instead of direct access to fields, whenever it's possible. This enables better debugging and encapsulation.

Regarding the underscore, a private field is a private field. Its name does not change its accessibility. It's a matter of naming convention, maybe two different teams worked on List and Dictionary and they named thing differently.

Generally C# developers tend to avoid underscore, but an exception can be made for private fields (see [here](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md))

Comment: Upvoted and thank you so much for your valuable time and for your kind efforts towards helping me.Appreciated :)